# ImportError: No module named 'utils'

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, anaconda, python-module

After installing Tensorflow, when I'm trying to run my code I get a single import error

```
from utils import *
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-b81aa0fdb889>", line 1, in <module>
    from utils import *

ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

even though I tried both

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-utils 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 python-utils
```

and if I look in the environment of my Anaconda Navigator the python-utils package appears to be installed.

My environment: macOS Mojave 10.14 + Tensorflow 1.12.0 + Python 3.5.6.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried

```
from python_utils import *
```

It says so in the [python-utils documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-utils/)

Comment: @patri Glad to help. Please help mark as correct answer if this is what you are looking for. Thanks!